Stuck while upgrading Ubuntu via remote GUI
I launched the upgrade of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 via remote desktop, but the connection dropped during the process and I can't connect anymore. Plugging a monitor doesn't work because I had set up a dummy monitor with xserver-xorg-video-dummy so I could use rdp even when no monitor was connected. The computer has an intel IGD.
I can connect via ssh and would like to see the upgrade status so it can be finished properly, but I get this :
/etc/update-manager
(update-manager:375248): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:14:20.527: cannot open display:

reboot is unadvised I think :
Operation inhibited by "UpdateManager" (PID 90229 "noble", user root), reason is "Updating System".
Please retry operation after closing inhibitors and logging out other users.
Alternatively, ignore inhibitors and users with 'systemctl reboot -i'.

Current display manager is gdm3
systemctl status display-manager.service
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-08-16 16:26:27 CEST; 4 weeks 1 day ago
    Process: 374647 ExecReload=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 374653 ExecReload=/bin/kill -SIGHUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 981 (gdm3)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 9302)
     Memory: 5.7M (peak: 7.3M)
        CPU: 185ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
             └─981 /usr/sbin/gdm3

Aug 16 16:26:28 ubu gdm3[981]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Aug 16 16:26:28 ubu gdm-autologin][1209]: gkr-pam: no password is available for user
Aug 16 16:26:28 ubu gdm-autologin][1209]: pam_unix(gdm-autologin:session): session opened for user ubi(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Aug 16 16:26:28 ubu gdm-autologin][1209]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly
Sep 14 18:51:33 ubu systemd[1]: Reloading GNOME Display Manager...
Sep 14 18:51:33 ubu systemd[1]: Reloaded GNOME Display Manager.
Sep 14 19:35:17 ubu systemd[1]: Reloading gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager...
Sep 14 19:35:17 ubu systemd[1]: Reloaded gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager.
Sep 15 16:10:57 ubu systemd[1]: Reloading gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager...
Sep 15 16:10:57 ubu systemd[1]: Reloaded gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager.

After ssh login it says :
Welcome to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-40-generic x86_64)

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.

0 updates can be applied immediately.

7 additional security updates can be applied with ESM Apps.

*** System restart required ***

Installer log :
tail -n 50 /var/log/dpkg.log
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status unpacked update-manager:all 1:24.04.6
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status half-configured update-manager:all 1:24.04.6
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status installed update-manager:all 1:24.04.6
2024-09-14 19:35:21 configure update-notifier:amd64 3.192.68build3 <none>
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status unpacked update-notifier:amd64 3.192.68build3
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status half-configured update-notifier:amd64 3.192.68build3
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status installed update-notifier:amd64 3.192.68build3
2024-09-14 19:35:21 configure apturl:amd64 0.5.2ubuntu23 <none>
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status unpacked apturl:amd64 0.5.2ubuntu23
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status half-configured apturl:amd64 0.5.2ubuntu23
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status installed apturl:amd64 0.5.2ubuntu23
2024-09-14 19:35:21 configure ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 1.539.1 <none>
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status unpacked ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 1.539.1
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status half-configured ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 1.539.1
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status installed ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 1.539.1
2024-09-14 19:35:21 configure ubuntu-desktop:amd64 1.539.1 <none>
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status unpacked ubuntu-desktop:amd64 1.539.1
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status half-configured ubuntu-desktop:amd64 1.539.1
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status installed ubuntu-desktop:amd64 1.539.1
2024-09-14 19:35:21 trigproc dictionaries-common:all 1.29.7 <none>
2024-09-14 19:35:21 status half-configured dictionaries-common:all 1.29.7
2024-09-14 19:35:22 status installed dictionaries-common:all 1.29.7
2024-09-14 19:35:22 trigproc ca-certificates:all 20240203 <none>
2024-09-14 19:35:22 status half-configured ca-certificates:all 20240203
2024-09-14 19:35:23 status installed ca-certificates:all 20240203
2024-09-14 19:35:23 trigproc linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic:amd64 6.8.0-44.44 <none>
2024-09-14 19:35:23 status half-configured linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic:amd64 6.8.0-44.44
2024-09-14 19:35:30 status installed linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic:amd64 6.8.0-44.44
2024-09-14 19:35:30 trigproc initramfs-tools:all 0.142ubuntu25.2 <none>
2024-09-14 19:35:30 status half-configured initramfs-tools:all 0.142ubuntu25.2
2024-09-14 19:35:35 status installed initramfs-tools:all 0.142ubuntu25.2
2024-09-14 19:35:36 trigproc linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 6.8.0-40.40 <none>
2024-09-14 19:35:36 status half-configured linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 6.8.0-40.40
2024-09-14 19:35:42 status installed linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic:amd64 6.8.0-40.40
2024-09-14 19:35:42 trigproc libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0:amd64 2.42.10+dfsg-3ubuntu3.1 <none>
2024-09-14 19:35:42 status half-configured libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0:amd64 2.42.10+dfsg-3ubuntu3.1
2024-09-14 19:35:42 status installed libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0:amd64 2.42.10+dfsg-3ubuntu3.1
2024-09-14 19:35:42 trigproc rsyslog:amd64 8.2312.0-3ubuntu9 <none>
2024-09-14 19:35:42 status half-configured rsyslog:amd64 8.2312.0-3ubuntu9
2024-09-14 19:35:42 status installed rsyslog:amd64 8.2312.0-3ubuntu9
2024-09-14 19:35:42 trigproc rygel:amd64 0.42.5-1ubuntu3 <none>
2024-09-14 19:35:42 status half-configured rygel:amd64 0.42.5-1ubuntu3
2024-09-14 19:35:42 status installed rygel:amd64 0.42.5-1ubuntu3
2024-09-14 19:35:42 trigproc sgml-base:all 1.31 <none>
2024-09-14 19:35:42 status half-configured sgml-base:all 1.31
2024-09-14 19:35:42 status installed docbook-xml:all 4.5-12
2024-09-14 19:35:42 status installed sgml-base:all 1.31
2024-09-14 19:35:42 trigproc libc-bin:amd64 2.39-0ubuntu8.3 <none>
2024-09-14 19:35:42 status half-configured libc-bin:amd64 2.39-0ubuntu8.3
2024-09-14 19:35:42 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.39-0ubuntu8.3

Can I simply reboot ?
How can I finnish the upgrade via ssh, or enable the local monitor ?

please append tail -n 50 /var/log/dpkg.log to the question (that's the last 50 lines of the package installer log file)

Reboot is needed at least because of the kernel update (new one is linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic, you're running ...-40-.... However, I don't see anything that would prevent normal boot of the system, so it must be safe to reboot it. All updates seem to be finished normally, it looks like there is nothing was interrupted in the middle of the update. That said, have a habit of running such things in a screen/tmux or vnc session that you can reattach to in case of network disconnect, to be safe.

I would, in this situation, kill 90229 - the graphical update manager in this case, and run a apt dist-upgrade. This should ensure that the required packages are installed, followed by a reboot.

Is it safe enough ? I have a service that needs to be active during work hours and was thinking to setup a new machine as backup before trying anything.

Safe enough is subjective. If possible, a new machine makes it safer.
